# Setting up sendmail to work as a client only?

Tags: email, unix, sendmail, aix

We are running sendmail-8.13.4 on AIX.

I need to update the configuration and make sendmail act as a relay client only, meaning it will only be used to send mail out of the host and NOT accept mail.

Here is my client.mc config:

```
include(`/usr/samples/tcpip/sendmail/m4/cf.m4')
VERSIONID(`sendmail config for aix7')
OSTYPE(`aixsample')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`myserver.com')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')
FEATURE(`accept_unqualified_senders')
FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl
FEATURE(`nullclient',`mail-relay.xxxx.myserver.com')dnl
define(`STATUS_FILE', `/etc/mail/statistics')dnl
define(`MAIL_HUB', `myserver.com.')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `myserver.com.')dnl
```

We have an MS Exchange server, so we are basically using sendmail on a particular AIX host to forward all email to the exchange server and let Exchange handle everything.

The above configuration works fine for sending email to recipients
    mail user@myserver.com

What I also need to do is be able to send the email with only specifying the alias part and not the domain, so if I do:

```
mail user    (omitting the @myserver.com recipient domain part)
```

I want sendmail to append the @myserver.com in this situation where a domain is not given. Is this possible without maintaining some sort of alias/list file for every possible userid > userid@mydomain.com?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use approach mentioned in sendmail FAQ 4.22 - make sendmail accept smtp connections **only** on (local) loopback ip interface.

[Sendmail FAQ 4.22 : Why can't I receive external mail?](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/general_issues_faq/#4.22)

It may be achieved by the following lines in sendmail.mc file used to generated sendmail.cf file:

```
dnl Do no listen on msa(587) port
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
dnl Listen on IPv6 loopback address
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1')dnl
dnl Listen on IPv4 loopback address
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but what I need is to be able to send email to an alias without the domain part and have sendmail append the domain part automatically. So if I use "mail testuser" it would translate into "mail testuser@mydomain.com". How can I do this?

Comment: Sendmail would append "this host email domain" ($j) to "naked" user name.  You can check it as non root user using `/usr/sbin/sendmail -Ac -bv testuser`